# classname not being recognised CSS styling

Tags: css, css-selectors

i have a submit button with the code inside a form

```
<li>
   <input id="zip" name="zipcode" type="submit" 
          class="zip-button" value="Find" tabindex="{counter name=tabindex}"/>
</li>

.zip-button{
    height:30px;
    ------}
.zip-button:focus,.zip-button:hover{------}
```

for some reason the zip is not getting any style.but if manually add it in jquery like

```
$("#zip").css({"height":"30px",...});
```

its working.As am very new to styling i couldn't figure it.

Comment: What are those `------`?

Comment: Where did you put your styles? Are they just floating around like that in your HTML? Are they in a CSS file? Is your page linked to the CSS file? Your CSS looks fine, but I don't know if the CSS is being loaded into the page correctly.

Comment: @Bolt  '----'represents code in that block.dint want to show all that junk so just used ---.  @Will my styling is in an external CSS file and is loaded at the beginning of base page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes the cascade in CSS is a possible reason for the that case. Another rule with higher precedence is able to overwrite the definition. Firebug is a great tool for "debugging" css code.
It shows, how the browser interprets the style sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Is your css directly in the page like that? if so, that is the reason.  You need to use inline styles, a style tag or an external css file.

inline:

```
<input style='height:30px;' ...
```

style tag:

```
<html>
     <head>
        <style type='text/css'> 
            .zip-button{ height:30px; }
        </style>
     ...
```

[external file](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/external.php)

Comment: i have an external file with the CSS for some reason only this particular class "zip-button" is not being recognised..all other styling parts are working fine

Answer (score 0):

sometimes we might be referring to minified css(abc.css.min) file in which some classes might be missing (my case)instead of the original source css.this might result in styles missing for few class which are absent in css.min ....we can find out this using FireBug...in this case we need to go back and set reference right...[am a beginner so bare with my technical terms usage]